# Django form request KeyError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have model `MyModel` as listed below. When I submit the form, in `/`, I got a`KeyError` at `/add` with exception value `name`. According to debugger, the error is in this line in `views.form_add`:

```
name = request.session['name']
```

What is wrong?

#### myapp/models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

#### myapp/forms.py

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

#### myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'main'),
    url(r'^add/', 'form_add'),
)
```

#### myapp/views.py

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = MyModelForm()
        args = {}
        args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'main.html', args)

def form_add(request):
    args = {}
    name = request.session['name']
    args['name'] = name
    mm = MyModel(name=name)
    mm.save()

    return render(request, 'add.html', args)
```

#### templates/main.html

```
<form method="POST" id="" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### templates/add.html

```
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

---

### Edition 1

#### myproject/settings.py (template context processors)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    )
```

### Edition 2 - solved

I rewrote my `main` function saving `MyModel` and `request.session['name']` as below.

```
def main(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            # I added the lines below to create MyModel and request
            request.session['name'] = name
            mm = MyModel.objects.create(name=name)
            mm.save()
            # the indentation was wrong
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = MyModelForm()
    # the indentation was wrong
    args = {}
    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'main.html', args)
```

Comment: do you have `django.core.context_processors.request` set in your template context processors? You cannot access request.session objects if you do not.

Comment: @karthikr, I don't have `django.core.context_processors.request`, but I also don't have in my other django projects. I inserted it and got the same error.

Comment: @karthikr context processors have nothing to do with whether or not you can access `request.session` in the view. They are for template contexts, hence the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very strange code. When your form is submitted, if it is valid, you put the `name` value in a variable *which is immediately thrown away*. You don't save the form, but again throw away the values. Whether or not the form is valid, you redirect immediately to the `add/` URL, where you assume that there is a `name` value in the session, despite never having saved anything to the session previously.

Your base problem is that there isn't a `name` key in the session, but I'm confused about why you think there would be, given the code you've shown.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your answer. With it I could fix the question and extend my understanding about Django.